# unable to build .dll after following the instructions

Tags: c++, qt, dll, cmd, makefile

I guess this is a simple question since I don't have much information about creating dll's

I wanted to use the deprecated Qt PieMenu in a project, I found the source code [here](https://github.com/sintegrial/qtsolutions).

After I did the necessary changes to the source code, I needed to build a dll from the source file (because it's licensed under LGPL).

The INSTALL.TXT file explains the steps.However, I'm always getting a .lib file instead of the dll.

I have no idea what I'm missing because I'm following the instructions without much understanding the whole idea.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you just followed the instruction in the repository, you will always get a static library (`.lib` file). It might be more complex, but at first, you should replace the line `CONFIG += static` with `CONFIG += shared` in all `.pro` files.

Comment: I did that, But I'm not sure if my generated libs are correct (The generated dll file is only about 100Kb, while the lib file generated before was about 4Mb)